# Odd problem with PSU

Tags: power-supply, current, amperage, 12v, watts

I don't know a much about electronics so please if you choose to help, layman terms would be appreciated.

I have an old 550w PC PSU. I have used it previously with an electronic air pump to pump up tyres. This electronic pump is made to work off a car battery normally.

Yesterday it just shut off when I applied the pump to the tyre. Now the PSU totally refuses to play with the pump, it just shuts down immediately when the pump is turned on.

I looked at the pump which has a 28A rating and the PSU on the 12v line has a 18A rating. I tried putting all the 12v lines together but that didn't help.

Comment: Do you have a multi-meter?

Comment: Yes, I have a multi-meter

Comment: Is there a fuse?

Comment: I suppose the multi-meter would have to have a fuse. The PSU does have a small glass fuse in it.

Comment: I meant the PSU. Can you see if the fuse is blown? If you can't you can take it out and resistance test it.

Comment: I can open up and have a look now, however the PSU does work fine with 12v fans so I assumed it wasn't a fuse.

Comment: The fuse is soldered in, Id have to take the board out to remove it. I did an Ohms test on it, appears to connect.

Comment: Does each output read 12V when turned on and not connected to anything?

Comment: I havn't tested that, I would have to take them all apart again as I have joined all ground, 5v and 12v together. I am happy to do that, what do you suspect?

Comment: Why can't you just test it from the plugs you use to connect it to the pump? You connected all the grounds but not the +V outputs, right?

Comment: I connected all the +12v together, the +5v together and the grounds together. It will take sometime disconnect all the grouped wires but if that will help me somehow to get it to work with the pump again, i'd be happy to.

Comment: Hmmm. Don't bother. If nothing visibly failed inside the PSU then it probably failed short rather than open but if it failed short then you shouldn't read 12V at all if the outputs are tied together. You would get...heat, smoke, and fire when you turned it on. I suppose you could test that.

Comment: I get a stable 12.01v reading, I was guessing its only a single transformer so it would be fine to connect them all, wasn't a very expensive PSU. Thank you very much for trying to get to the bottom on my dilemma. I guess there is a small chance the pump wants more starting power now than it did a month ago.

Comment: Sounds like an inrush current problem to me. Can you try to add a tiny resistance (<ohm) in series with the output?

Answer (score 1):

Power supply has 18A rated load maximum. Pump has 28A rated load it wants to have. You exceeded the power supply maximum and power supply is now broken. Power supplies do not handle overloading forever, they can get damaged.

Comment: But it still does work with a 12v 6amp rated fan I have. What could be damaged to only allow it to work for small loads?

Comment: Unfortunately true of way too many power supplies.  I had to qualify a wall adapter years ago and tested maybe 20 samples from different manufacturers.  80% did not meet spec for load capability, especially at max temp rating, and maybe 40% failed destructively.  A good supply should last indefinitely by protecting itself from current overload. (Hiccup, const current, shutdown, etc.)

Comment: Oh good eye. I totally read those current ratings in reverse.

Comment: @puzzled If the supply works for smaller loads maybe the pump's friction has increased needing higher starting current that the supply can't handle.  Is there a way to re-lubricate the piston?

Comment: You did not give that information before. If the PSU still works wirh light loads, it may or may not be damaged then. Maybe the pump has gradually worn out and takes more current than before, so the overcurrent limit of the PSU kicks in. It still means your rated load is higher that what PSU is specified for, so you should find a power supply that provides enough current.

Comment: Sorry for not providing all relevant information. I guess it is possible the pump is requiring a bit more ooomph to kick start. I could get a amp measurement from starting it with a battery maybe?

Comment: What is really surprising to me is that it ever worked at all considering the amp ratings of each unit. I was thinking perhaps I fluked it somehow, may of the wires where cut when I was using it successfully (only cut because I could be bothered trying to tie them down in the PC).

Comment: @puzzled Your multimeter can handle 40A+? I doubt it. That's probably going to be the range of the starting current.

Comment: Good call, I won't bother, believe its 10amp max.

Comment: Power supplies are also not made from ideal components that last forever. Especially when used with higher than rated load, the capacitors can wear out faster than in normal use due to higher ripple current and heating it causes.

Comment: Thanks for your help, perhaps the capacitors are worn down, they say 470uF 200v on them, not sure what that means :) Oh well, may just have to repurpose this PSU for something else *scratches head*

Comment: Those are the mains input caps. The ones that in this case would most likely wear out would be the caps on 12V output.

Comment: LOL, told you I was a layman. Ive looked around there and sure enough there are a bunch of caps that have some kind of brown substance on top that looks like rust, could that be damage from pushing the unit to hard?

Comment: The capacitors are dead then. Don't use it any more. Pressure has built up and they have vented pressure from the top, along with electrolyte. It may just be old age, but it's also possible they wore out faster with the extra load. It's time to recycle it (or change the caps).